# Need help to access variable within a method

Tags: java, android, scope, global-variables

I have the below code:

```
public OuterClass extends Activity {

protected int width;
protected int height;

public void onCreate(....){

t1.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
            public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right,
                    int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight,
                    int oldBottom) {
                UIThroughCode.this.width = right - left;
                UIThroughCode.this.height = bottom - top;
}

}

int newwidth = (int) (42 + (12.5 - (width / 2)));
int newheight = (int) (18 + (12.5 - (height / 2)));
```

I am declaring the width and height at the top of the class as global variables, and I am changing the values of those variables in the addLayoutChangeListener method. However, when I try to use the changed values in the above two statements, to calculate a new width and height, the values of width and height are zero, meaning they have not been changed by the addLayoutChangeListener method.

Could you kindly help me to access the changed values of width and height from the addLayoutChangeListener method?

Comment: What's `UIThroughCode`?

Comment: Also, variables don't automatically update, if that's what you're thinking. `int a = 5; int b = a + 1; a = 42;` does not set `b` to 43.

Comment: Sorry for the mixup! Disregard UIThroughCode. UIThroughCode.this.width should be just width, and same with UIThroughCode.this.height (should be height).

Comment: When you add a change listener, it adds the listener but doesn't wait for it to happen.  So what you've done is to tell the program "Do this when the layout changes", but then you go ahead and use `width` and `height` right away, before the layout has had a chance to change.  Getting this right is tricky because you don't want to do a "wait" on the main thread.